# Display categories not related to an entry

Tags: craft3, categories, relatedto

I'm trying to output a list of categories that are **not** related to a particular entry (in order to show a list of services other than the service related to the current entry).

I have this code which lists the category that **is** related to the current entry:

```
<ul>
  {% set categories = craft.categories.group('services').relatedTo(entry).all() %}
  {% nav category in categories %}
    <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Is there a way of turning this on its head, so that the other, non-related categories are displayed? Something like a `notRelatedTo(entry)` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all ids and exclude them from your query

```twig
{% set excludeIds = craft.categories.group('services').relatedTo(entry).ids() %}
{% for category in craft.categories.where(['!=', 'elements.id', excludeIds]).all() %}
```

If your relation field is in your entry you can do

```twig
{% set categories = craft
    .categories
    .section('services')
    .where(['!=', 'elements.id', entry.category.ids()])
    .all()
%}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin. I'm still having a problem with this though, as it's now generating a database exception. This is what I have now:

    `<ul>
        {% set excludeIds = craft.categories.group('services').relatedTo(entry).ids() %}
        {% for category in craft.categories.where(['!=', 'elements.id', excludeIds]).all() %}
            <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>`